# Firebase initWithUrl crashes on iOS 5.1

Tags: ios, ipad, firebase, ios5.1

I'm developing a Firebase app to use on my old iPad first generation (iOS 5.1.1). It works fine on the simulator and on other devices but, when I load it on the iPad to test, I receive a crash like this one:

```
#0  0x33860f86 in objc_msgSend ()
#1  0x33862f94 in objc_retain ()
#2  0x000d26a0 in -[FRepoManager setQueue:] at /Users/mtse/Dev/firebase/firebase-client-objc/Firebase/Firebase/Core/FRepoManager.m:24
#3  0x33fdc5aa in dispatch_once_f$VARIANT$up ()
#4  0x000d1a80 in _dispatch_once [inlined] at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk/usr/include/dispatch/once.h:68
#5  0x000d1a70 in +[FRepoManager singleton] at /Users/mtse/Dev/firebase/firebase-client-objc/Firebase/Firebase/Core/FRepoManager.m:37
#6  0x000e6736 in -[Firebase initWithUrl:] at /Users/mtse/Dev/firebase/firebase-client-objc/Firebase/Firebase/Firebase.m:54
#7  0x000c6f82 in -[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] at /xxx/AppDelegate.m:25
#8  0x3337acaa in -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForURL:payload:suspended:] ()
#9  0x333747dc in -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] ()
#10 0x33342ac2 in -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] ()
#11 0x33342566 in -[UIApplication sendEvent:] ()
#12 0x33341f3a in _UIApplicationHandleEvent ()
#13 0x3393422a in PurpleEventCallback ()
#14 0x35c16522 in __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ ()
#15 0x35c164c4 in __CFRunLoopDoSource1 ()
#16 0x35c15312 in __CFRunLoopRun ()
#17 0x35b984a4 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#18 0x35b9836c in CFRunLoopRunInMode ()
#19 0x3337386a in -[UIApplication _run] ()
#20 0x33370cd4 in UIApplicationMain ()
#21 0x000c778c in main at /xxx/main.m:14
```

This happens as soon as the code reaches this line:

```
    Firebase *ref = [[Firebase alloc] initWithUrl:kFirebaseURL];
```

I tried even downgrading the Firebase framework to older ones but the problem persists. I have the -ObjC linker flag set too. Any ideas of how this can be solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, iOS 5.x is no longer supported by the Firebase SDK.  You can try [old versions](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/changelog.html) of the SDK to see if one works, but offhand I do not know.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this by downgrading to [v1.0.8](https://cdn.firebase.com/ObjC/Firebase.framework-1.0.8.zip) of the framework (direct link to ZIP file) — this is the newest version that doesn't experience this crash on an iPad 1 with iOS 5.1.1.